# How to validate file transfers(cp,scp command) in unix shell scripts by checksum or md5 command?

Tags: unix, checksum, md5sum

I have a unix shell script that creates and transfers files from one path to another ( either from same server or from another)
Then there is transfer of files to this folder from either same or different server.

I'm unable to identify a method through which I could verify my file transfer md5 or checksum through a script.usually I take the checksum of the source and destination folders and match them manually.

Please advise

Comment: Utilities like `md5sum`, `sha1sum`, `shasum`, etc. all have a checking option which causes them to return a status if the checksums read from a file don't match the actual files. Using these should be rather straightforward.

Comment: @Hasturkun, this is true for Linux utils, Solaris `digest` for example do not have this option.

Answer (score 2):

In your script you can insert line like this:

```
sha1sum <list of files> >files.sha1
```

to generate file with sha1 sums. Then you transfer all the files (including file with hashes) to the target place, for example:

```
scp /path/* user@host:localion
```

and then exec (via `ssh` for example) this to check the `sha1` hash of files on target:

```
ssh user@host "cd location; sha1sum -c files.sha1"
```

This all is just example you should tune it for your environment

In Solaris you can use command:

```
digest -a sha1 location/* >/directory/hash1
scp /path/* user@host:localion
ssh user@host "cd location; digest -a sha1 *" >/directory/hash2
diff /directory/hash1 /directory/hash2
```

(the last command will compare hashes from local and remote sites)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However. I use sunOS(Sparc- Enterprise) and the command md5sum,sha1sum does not work. Please advise. I can see I can use cksum , digest command to fetch the checksum but unsure how do I compare if both the checksum are accurate through the script.